# Subquotients of l-adic cohomology vs l-adic cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

When people talk about absolute Galois representations that are subquotients of l-adic cohomology of smooth projective varieties I don't understand how important is the "subquotients" part.

If we require the Hodge-Tate weights to be symmetric is such a representation itself l-adic cohomology of a smooth projective variety?

Also what if instead of subquotients we asked about subrepresentations or quotients?

Comment: As for the last question: it is believed, but has not been proven, that the Galois representation coming from $l$-adic cohomology of smooth projective varieties (at least over number fields) are semisimple. This would mean that subrepresentations, quotients, and subquotients all coincide. I suspect not all of them are expected to come up as full cohomology groups, but not sure how one would go around proving that.

Comment: A necessary condition for a subquotient of cohomology to arise as H^i is that the characteristic polynomials of all Frobenius elements have rational coefficients. Another one is that for representations of even Weil weight w the multiplicity of the HT weight w/2 has to be non-zero because $h^{i,i}\neq 0$ for smooth projective varieties.

Comment: For $K$ a num. field and $A/K$ a geom. simple ab. surface with quaternionic mult. (plenty exist), the $\ell$-adic ($\ell$ large) Gal. rep. of A is the square of a 2-dimensional Gal. rep. $\rho$ valued in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$ which looks exactly like it should come from $H^1$ of a var.: integral Frob. traces, pure of wt. $1$, crystalline at all primes above $\ell$ with Hodge-Tate weights $\{0,-1\}$, … But if there were a smooth projective variety $X$ with $\ell$-adic $H^1\cong \rho$, then the same would be true of $H^1$ of its Alb., contradicting simplicity of $A$ by the Tate conj.

Comment: (Seeing as I barely know what an Albanese is, please let me know if I’ve said something stupid above!) Anyway very vaguely speaking the point is something like: not all the decompositions of Galois representations are reflected in geometry “on the nose”, like just because the $\ell$-adic rep. splits up doesn’t mean that’s coming from a literal decomposition at the level of varieties, but rather some $\ell$-adic combination of maps of varieties (hopefully that makes sense, I only ever think of abelian varieties admittedly so it’s possible it doesn’t!).

Comment: A typical example is when a finite group $G$ acts on a variety $X$ and hence on its $\ell$-adic cohomology $H^i(X_{\overline{K}}, \overline{\mathbf{Q}}_\ell)$. The cohomology groups decompose into irreducible representations of $G$, and the isotypical components of this decomposition are direct summands of the Galois representation. There is no reason why these summands should be isomorphic on the nose to some $\ell$-adic cohomology groups. However, they certainly should be regarded as 'coming from geometry' (and they have integral characteristic polynomials of Frobenius etc.).